# Oil leak on 2004 Chevy Silverado 2500 HD

Tags: engine

These are the best photos I could take off the oil leak. It looks like it's flashing on to the Rusty Circular thing in the Second picture. It looks like the leak is originating at the transfer case. Can someone help me diagnose the problem further, if you need further information/pictures please let me know

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]